# C++ - unique_ptr within a unordered_map leads to errors

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I have a program that's giving me a vague error, so rather than post hundreds of lines of code I have made this simplified version:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct s
{
    int height;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<s>> children;
};

void InitWD(s &wd_ptr, int height, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<s>> children) //Initialize a WindowData
{
    wd_ptr.children=children;
    wd_ptr.height=height;
}

int main()
{
  s test;
  test.height=1;
  test.children=std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<s>>();
  std::unique_ptr<s> ptr(new s);
  InitWD(*ptr, 2, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<s>>());
  test.children.emplace("two", std::move(ptr));
}
```

The error (GCC 4.8 with C++11) is regarding either the `unique_ptr` or the `unordered_map`, I believe:

```
error: use of deleted function 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<s>]'
```

Perhaps somewhere in the code a `unique_ptr` is being copied?  That's the only thing I could think of that would cause such an error.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
wd_ptr.children=children;
```

This tries to *copy* `children` into `wd_ptr.children`. You need to change it to:

```
wd_ptr.children = std::move(children);
```

It's rather unfortunate that neither gcc nor clang is able to produce a diagnostic that actually tells you which line of your code is wrong.

Comment: That's really interesting; g++ usually shows which line of code, but it [clearly does not for this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80e9b5ae43362e32), even for g++ v6.3 (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c19194654682c731). Should this be filed as a bug in gcc?

Comment: @Justin I think so. You can file a bug if you want, although I probably wouldn't bother since I figure it'll probably be a duplicate of an existing bug, and I'm too lazy to check.

Comment: When templates are used, it is typical to point to an immediate source of the error, somewhere within the template implementation. However, most compilers also add more diagnostic "Notice: when instantiating at line...". Usually when you walk up on that path, you eventually reach your code at the problematic line. Note - the compiler really can't do better, because the bug may be either in the template implementation or in how it is used.